# Enable storing of taxonomy term name instead of ID in views filter criteria

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, features

**Background**
I use Features module to deploy the code to my stagging. For e.g. I have a feature which exports:

- content type - *Player*
- Taxonomy term on this content type of vocab - *Medals*
- View which lists the *Player* with filter type: `Content: Has taxonomy term (=gold)`

*Medals* has three terms - *gold*, *silver*, and *bronze*.
In the feature the vocabulary is being exported while the terms are not. I need to add the terms manually again on the server.

**Problem**
The feature exports the term id of the term instead of the name (tid : 1). So, when I enable the feature on the stagging server, and if the term name for `tid : 1` is silver. The views filter criteria is changed and it is conflicting with the use case.
I was just wondering if there is a way to export the views taxonomy filter name instead of id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for filtering via term name. However, I came up with a workaround where I was able to featurize the taxonomy terms too.
I'm using [UUID Features Integration](https://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) for the same:

> The UUID Features Integration module provides a mechanism for exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module. What's that you say? You thought features was only for configuration? This module is meant to be used in the cases where certain pieces of content straddle the line between pure content and configuration.